# Calculate Duration based on a criteria in another column in SQL for specific IDs

Tags: sql, datetime, duration

I have a table called Audit like below:

| ID | Record | AccessedDTTM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | Sign In | 2021-03-23 04:41:33.770 |
| 16 | Session End - Sign Out | 2021-03-23 04:42:33.770 |
| 17 | Sign In | 2021-03-01 00:03:04.070 |
| 17 | Session End - Sign Out | 2021-03-01 00:33:52.717 |
| 18 | Sign In | 2021-03-01 01:31:00.527 |
| 18 | Schedule | 2021-03-01 01:31:31.407 |
| 18 | Charge | 2021-03-01 01:43:27.427 |
| 18 | Session End - Sign Out | 2021-03-01 01:47:27.940 |

I need to calculate the duration of the time accessed by the Users with Id 16 and 18. The duration should be based on their Record of Sign In and Session End - Sign Out entries.

I tried this query :
select DateDiff(second, (Select AccessedDTTM from Audit Where Record = 'Sign In'), (Select AccessedDTTM from Audit  Where Record = 'Session End - Sign Out'))
as Duration  Foom Audit
Where ID In (16, 18)

But I am getting an error as below :
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can someone please help me with the proper query to achieve this result? Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Skip the subqueries, do a JOIN instead.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       datediff(second, 
                min(case when Record = 'Sign in' then AccessedDTTM end),
                max(case when Record = 'Session End - Sign Out' then AccessedDTTM end)
               ) as diff
from audit
where id in (16, 18)
group by id;
```

Making some reasonable assumptions about the data, you can simplify this to:

```
select id,
       datediff(second, min(AccessedDTTM), max(AccessedDTTM)
               ) as diff
from audit
where id in (16, 18) and
      record in ('Sign in', 'Session End - Sign Out')
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, The query worked like a charm for me. The max and min aggregate function did the work. Thank you again for guiding me! :)